# How to do math operations with string?

Tags: python, for-loop, math, types, calculator

If a have the string `calculation = '1+1x8'`. How can I convert this into `calculation = 1+1*8`? I tried doing something like

```
for char in calculation:
    if char == 'x':
        calculation = calculation.replace('x', *)

    # and

    if char == '1':
        calculation = calculation.replace('1', 1)
```

This clearly doesn't work, since you can't replace just one character with an integer. The entire string needs to be an integer, and if I do that it doesn't work either since I can't convert `'x'` and `'+'` to integers

Comment: `.replace()` replaces a *string* with a *string*.

Comment: You are basically asking "how do I write a parser", which is quite a broad topic.

Comment: First change `x` to `*`, then evaluate the string. @LuccasBrandao

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like:

```
def parse_exp(s):
    return eval(s.replace('x','*'))
```

and expand for whatever other exotic symbols you want to use.

To limit the risks of eval you can also eliminate bad characters:

```
import string

good = string.digits + '()/*+-x'

def parse_exp(s):
    s2 = ''.join([i for i in s if i in good])
    return eval(s2.replace('x','*'))
```

Edit: additional bonus is that the in-built `eval` function will take care of things like parenthesis and general calculation rules :)

Edit 2: As another user pointed out, `eval`[can be dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). As such, only use it if your code will ever only run locally

Comment: Additional bonus that eval will execute *any* arbitrary code and so is potentially a large security risk

Comment: Valid but the OP asked for a way of evaluating expressions without specifying further. Why have him write a complicated parser when he can use something simple?

Comment: because it's a big security flaw as i said. anyway, it is not hard to write a simple parser if they just want to support a few operators like multiply, add etc., and they would learn from doing this

Comment: If it's so easy I suggest you write one and post it :)

Comment: here's a pretty complete one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/6260170

Answer (score 5):

Let's use a more complicated string as an example: `1+12x8`. What follows is a rough outline; you need to supply the implementation for each step.

First, you tokenize it, turning `1+12x8` into `['1', '+', '12', 'x', '8']`. For this step you need to write a tokenizer or a lexical analyzer. This is the step where you define your operators and literals.

Next, you convert the token stream into a parse tree. Perhaps you represent the tree as an [S-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) `['+', '1', ['x', '12', '8']]` or `[operator.add, 1, [operator.mul, 12, 8]]`. This step requires writing a parser, which requires you to define things like the precedence of your operators.

Finally, you write an evaluator that can reduce your parse tree to a single value. Doing this in two steps might yield

1. `[operator.add, 1, [operator.mul, 12, 8]]` to `[operator.add, 1, 96]`
2. `[operator.add, 1, 96]` to `97`

Answer (score 0):

Adding code to what chepner suggested:

Tokenize  '1+12x8' ->  ['1', '+', '12', 'x', '8'].
Use order of operation '/*+-' -> reduce calculation 1 + (12*8)
Return the answer

```
import re
import operator




operators = {
        '/': operator.truediv,
        'x':operator.mul,
        '+':operator.add,
        '-':operator.sub,

    }

def op(operators, data):
    # apply operating to all occurrences 

    for p in operators:
        while p in data:
            x = data.index(p)
            replacer = operators.get(p)(int(data[x-1]) , int(data[x+1]))
            data[x-1] = replacer
            del data[x:x+2]


    return data[0]


def func(data):
    # Tokenize

    d = [i for i in re.split('(\d+)', data) if i ]

    # Use order of operations 
    d = op(operators, d)

    return d


s1 = "1+1x8"
s2 = '2-4/2+5'


s = func(s1) # 9
print(s)

t = func(s2) #-5
print(t)
```